# Delete the line from a file if 5th column had hypen

Tags: shell, awk, sh

Example file test.txt

```
12-3 34r5 2324 - 23ed423 2322
3-4  2-32  45   34ed  -   232
e-r  34-2  234  232de - 232
23-4 23-2 232 - - 232de
- - - - - -
```

The ouptut expected is

```
12-3 34r5 2324 - 23ed423 2322
```

The condition is, line containing hypen " - " on the column 5 should be removed from the file.
is it possible using a sed or awk

i tried something like `awk '{print $5}' test.txt|grep '-'|xargs sed -i -e /-/d` but didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '$5=="-"{next} 1' Input_file > temp && mv temp Input_file
```

***OR***

```
awk '$5!="-"' Input_file > temp && mv temp Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** It simply taking cursor to next position when `-` found in 5th field OR in 2nd solution simply print those lines which doesn't have `-` in its 5th field.

Comment: Thanks, both the commands worked only thing is i have to save the output to the file again. like `awk '$5!="-"' test.txt > test.txt`